# Sending email - Attachments -Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2

Tags: canvas, dynamic, powerapps

I am stuck with sending emails in the Power Apps canvas app.  After completing the form, I must send a notification email with all the fields and attachments.

I have a problem building dynamically the `attachments` field of  `Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2`. Below is my code and what it does is to print the attachment values in the email instead of attaching the file.

No issues if I hardcode the attachment field inside the function. The problem is only when I pass as a variable. I need to pass as a variable because I have 5 attachments and not all 5 images are loaded by the user.  So when there is an empty file that I try to send am getting an error. So I decided to check if the file is empty and then stop sending the remaining files.

Is it really possible and allowed to pass a variable for the `attachment` field? If that's not possible then how we can send only non-empty images?

```
If(IsBlank(Image6.Image),
Set(attach,"{IsHtml: true,Attachments:Table({Name:""Image2.jpg"", ContentBytes:Image7.Image, '@odata.type':""""})}"),
Set(attach,"{IsHtml: true,Attachments:Table({Name:""Image2.jpg"", ContentBytes:Image7.Image, '@odata.type':""""})}"));

Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(User().Email & ";" & varMgrEmail & ";" & varContractorEmail,"Haulage Inspection Form",varEmailBody & ";"& attach)
```

I tried building the attachment field dynamically but is not recognized and printing as text in the email body.